# Length of a plane curve in polar coordinate

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, plane-curves, polar-coordinates

Consider the plane curve $\gamma$ in polar coordinates:
$$
r=r_0+e^{\lambda\theta}, \quad \theta_1 \le \theta \le \theta_2,
$$
where $r_0,\lambda,\theta_1>0$. Is it possible to compute explicitly the length of $\gamma$?

Comment: Use $\int_a^b\|\gamma'(t)\|dt$, where $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, with the usual change of coordinates.

Comment: @Sigur I know that formula, it doesn't answer my question!

Comment: Why not? What did you think?

Comment: @Sigur The question seems clear enough! I'm not saying that I need the formula for the length a curve.

Comment: @Mercy: How does the formula not answer your question? Plug in your parametric equation and solve the integral -- symbolically if you can, numerically if you must. That's how you compute it. (In other words, the _explicit_ answer to your question is "yes").

Comment: @HenningMakholm Read carefully please. I'm asking whether there is a closed form for "an integral"!

Comment: @Mercy: Your question as currently written does not mention anything about closed forms.

Comment: @Mercy Actually, your question is "Is it possible to compute explicitly the length of $\gamma$?" The answer is "yes" and some posters have given some clues as how to go about the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general way of doing this, but I assume you are not familiar with it so let's look at your particular example. In Cartesian coordinates, your curve looks like

$$ \gamma (\theta)
= \begin{pmatrix}
r\cos\theta\\
r\sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
\left(r_0 +e^{\lambda \theta}\right)r\cos\theta\\
\left(r_0 +e^{\lambda \theta}\right)r\sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore, the tangent is 
$$
\frac{d\gamma}{d\theta}= \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 e^{\theta  \lambda } \lambda  \cos\theta-\sin\theta \left(e^{\theta  \lambda }+r_0\right) \\
 e^{\theta  \lambda } \lambda  \sin\theta+\cos\theta \left(e^{\theta  \lambda }+r_0\right)
\end{array}
\right)\ ,$$
and its norm is calculated easily using trigonometrical identities to be
$$\left|\frac{d\gamma}{d\theta}\right|=\sqrt{e^{2 \theta  \lambda } \left(1+\lambda ^2\right)+2 e^{\theta  \lambda } r_0+r_0^2}$$

The length is given by integrating $\left|\frac{d\gamma}{d\theta}\right|$ from $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$.

Comment: What do you get when you integrate? that's precisely what I'm asking for!

Comment: @Mercy I plugged it in Mathematica. It gives a nasty result which is much too long and cumersome to copy here, but it is a "closed form" as you hoped.

Answer (score 1):

This can be very slightly less excruciating.  Every polar curve $r = f(\theta)$ can be written as the parametric equations $x(\theta) = f(\theta) \cos(\theta)$, $y(\theta) = f(\theta)\sin(\theta)$.  You can do a chain rule calculation with a little trigonometric magic to crunch it down to 
$$ds = \sqrt{x'(\theta)^2 + y'(\theta)^2}\,d\theta = \sqrt{r^2 + r'(\theta)^2}\,d\theta.$$

You have $r(\theta) = r_0 + e^{\lambda\theta}.$  Then $r'(\theta) = \lambda e^{\lambda \theta},$ so
$$ds = \sqrt{(r_0 + e^{\lambda\theta})^2 + \lambda^2 e^{2\lambda\theta}}\,d\theta
= \sqrt{(1 + \lambda^2)e^{2\lambda\theta} + 2r_0 e^{\lambda\theta} + r_0^2}\,d\theta$$
This agreees with the form obtained by yohBS above.

You then need to embark down this path
$$\int ds = \int \sqrt{(1 + \lambda^2)e^{2\lambda\theta} + 2r_0 e^{\lambda\theta} + r_0^2}\,d\theta = \int {\sqrt{(1 + \lambda^2)e^{2\lambda\theta} + 2r_0 e^{\lambda\theta} + r_0^2}\over e^{-\lambda x}} e^{\lambda\theta}d\theta$$
Now put $z = e^{\lambda \theta}$ and you get left with
$$\int ds = {\sqrt{(1 + \lambda^2)z^2 + 2r_0 z + r^2_0}\over z}\, dz $$
Now try completing the square and doing a trigonometric substitution.